# Выполнение команды в оболочке Kali Nethunter

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Я хочу запустить команду metasploit в оболочку терминала  кали, что-то типа такого su -c "bootkali && msfconsole" но проблема в том, что команда bootkali завершается только после закрытия терминала а мне надо выполнить команду внутри него. Как мне это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

в общем решением было то, что я подредактировал bootkali, там была строка с custom_command и я в ней custom_command заменил на msfconsole и теперь можно запускать так su -c "bootkali msfconsole"